# I am a CS bachelor student and want to learn Electronics, which calculus book should i use?

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

first off i am weak at calculus, a complete newbie. I am good at programming but i was planning to dive into automation industry and Internet Of things, so i bought a Art of electronics as it was recommended for any newbie in electronic automation but then i saw the book used calculus for explanation, so i bought George f Simmons to do pre-calculus (sharpen the sword a lil bit ;) ) and now i am done with pre-calculus.

- I need a calculus book that would benefit me given my above background, suggestions?
- I do not want a book like the ones who help score in exams, i want something that would explain to the core why? and how?
- I will learn physics too in the future because i like it.
- An interesting book with lots of real world examples would  be nice.

Comment: Shouldn't you be taking physics and calculus in your first semester of college?

Comment: it got skipped as i got directly admitted int o 3rd semester because i had CS diploma leverage. :(

Comment: Lang's *A First Course in Calculus* and Marsden and Weinstein's *Calculus* would probably both be good for you. I like the first one a bit better, but the second one has a good student guide and is (legally) freely available online here: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/volume/Calculus/

Answer (score 0):

My favorite book for me during high school was AP Calculus by Princeton Review, although Barron's, Kaplan, or any other book that acts as a comprehensive concise textbook was also useful.

I found the textbooks to be overly long and detailed with information that was completely unnecessary. The examples numbered in amounts a little bit too much, and the explanations too long to hold my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Gilbert Strang's Calculus text sounds like it would be a good fit, and furthermore you can either buy the most recent edition or you can download an older edition for free: http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/textbook/.

More standard texts that you might like are by Stewart, Thomas & Finney, Briggs & Cochran, and (my personal favorite, for the non-math major) Earl Swokowski.